# Simple Getting Started Istio Helm Install

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, istio

I'm trying to follow either of the following instructions:

- https://istio.io/docs/setup/kubernetes/helm-install/
- https://github.com/istio/istio/tree/master/install/kubernetes/helm/istio

```
    ~ helm repo add istio.io https://storage.googleapis.com/istio-prerelease/daily-build/master-latest-daily/charts
    
    ~ helm repo list

    NAME        URL                                                                                   
    stable      https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com                                      
    local       http://127.0.0.1:8879/charts                                                          
    istio.io    https://storage.googleapis.com/istio-prerelease/daily-build/master-latest-daily/charts
    
    ~ helm repo update
    
    ~ helm install install/kubernetes/helm/istio --name istio --namespace istio-system
    Error: failed to download "install/kubernetes/helm/istio" (hint: running `helm repo update` may help)
    
    ~ helm dependency update install/kubernetes/helm/istio
    
    Error: could not find <current directory>/install/kubernetes/helm/istio: stat 
    <current directory>/install/kubernetes/helm/istio: no such file or directory
```

How do I resolve this error and get the Istio Helm chart to install?

Comment: I downvoted because there is no question in the post as originally written.

Comment: @meh, The question was how do I resolve the error get the Istio helm chart to install.

Comment: @meh, I thought the question was obvious, but I added it explicitly for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer my own question for anyone else with the same issue:

Don't use the public helm repo.

Download a release archive from:

https://github.com/istio/istio/releases

Unpack it, navigate into the istio root directory, then you can successfully do:

Helm 2.x syntax:

```
helm install install/kubernetes/helm/istio --name istio --namespace istio-system
```

Helm 3.x syntax:

```
helm install istio install/kubernetes/helm/istio --namespace istio-system
```

Comment: Error: unknown flag: --name

Comment: sure, Helm 3 changed the the syntax. My original answer was written well before Helm 3 was released. I updated with Helm 3 syntax.

Comment: Not working on Helm 3.3. For me above is no solution. Error: failed to download "install/kubernetes/helm/istio" (hint: running `helm repo update` may help) version.BuildInfo{Version:"v3.3+unreleased"